# Launch Application As Administrator From Form Application

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2008

I am just starting out with VB.net and building simple applications to help me work better.
I am creating a form application using Visual Studio Express VB 2008.
In this form, there would be buttons to launch applications installed in the computer.
Ideally, some applications require to launch as normal user and some as administrator.
I would be providing an option for the user to enter their administrator credentials within that same form and would use that to launch the applications that require administrator access.
Unfortunately, am not able to build the code due to this error: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Security.SecureString'
Here is the code have written:

```
Private Sub cmd_button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd_button.Click
Dim passwd As New System.Security.SecureString
Dim proc As New ProcessStartInfo
passwd = password_box.Text
passwd.Clear()
With Proc
    .FileName = "cmd.exe"
    .Username = username_box.Text
    .Passwd = passwd
End With
Process.Start(proc)
End Sub
```

Hope to get some help here, had tried Googling and searching through so many forums and as well as on Stackoverflow, but got results to work on C#, VB.Net was not able to find, or maybe something was not going clear on me. Hope someone here can help.

Comment: Windows already has a (reasonably) well understood UI for prompting for credentials (if necessary) when launching applications as administrator. Why are you building a custom UI for the same?

Comment: Yes, Am building a form with buttons that can launch applications as we require quickly by navigating to this form i built.
We have alot of applications that we launch and use to support, hence need this form to launch as normal user and then those applications within this form that require admin access should fetch the pre-filled admin credentials and launch automatically without having to ask for admin credentials again.

Comment: It's really not necessary to start the title of every VB.NET question with "VB.NET". In fact, we don't like that here. Please stop doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run an application as Administrator you set the `.Verb` property to `"runas"` and the `UseShellExecute` property to `True` on the process like this:

```
Dim process As New Process()
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe "
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
process.Start()
```

This will prompt for credentials if the current user is not a member of the administrators group of give a UAC prompt if they are (and UAC is turned on).

You cannot give it credentials to use. This is by design so what you are trying to do will not work as you want it to.

Comment: Thank you for this Matt, i did try this and it works, but is there a way i can automatically fill out the UAC username/password/domain without having the user to enter it every time?
Something like I store the admin credentials in a variable and pass those into UAC when it pops up and pass it without having to show the user the UAC?

Comment: No you cannot do that. UAC is a security mechanism. It is unlikely that MS would allow you to inject credentials into this as this would be an easy way to try a brute force attack.

Comment: Now I have come up with another solution/option for this.
I would be having two Forms. 'Form1' for non-Admin apps and 'Form2' to Admin apps.
Now, I would want to invoke 'Form2' from 'Form1', when i click a button on 'Form1' it should bring the UAC and ask for admin-username/password and it should run 'Form2' as admin.
Could you please help me with a code for invoking the 'Form2' with a UAC prompt please.?

Comment: The UAC token applies to the process, you cannot have differing tokens for different forms. Have a look at this for more information: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16796/Riding-the-Vista-UAC-elevator-up-and-down